# How to catch function passing value in print function?

Tags: flutter, dart

I know it's a very sily question, but I need to know the reply. If anyone can help me with patience.

I need to catch this value "8" in a `print()` function from this function `fac.getFactorial(8)`

How can I do that?
Here is my code. Thanks in advance.

```
void main() {
  Factorial fac = Factorial();
  fac.getFactorial(8);
  int? p2 = fac.p1;
  print(p2);
}

class Factorial {
  int? p1;
  int getFactorial(int n) {
    p1 = n;
    if (n == 1) {
      return 1;
    }
    return n * getFactorial(n - 1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `p1??=n;` this means n will be only assign when it is null. You can also do if null check.

```dart
  int getFactorial(int n) {
    p1 ??= n;
```